# Why can't I comment out an updatepanel in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, comments, repeater

I made a blank page and added the following resulting in a correctly running page:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

then i changed it to the following:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <!--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">-->
    <!--</asp:UpdatePanel>-->
```

why is it this this results in an error saying i cant have a "-->" literal inside an update panel!?

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
<!--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">-->
<!--</asp:UpdatePanel>-->
```

This is correct:

```
<%--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    </asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
```

EDIT:

As explained in https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Using-Server-Side-Comments-with-ASP.NET-2.0- —

> **ASP.NET supports a little known feature called “server-side comments” that you can use to completely disable code/controls/html in
> a page.  Server-side comments in ASP.NET are delimited using a <%--
> --%>**
> **The key difference is that with client-side comments it is the browser which is ignoring the content within them.  Code/controls
> within client-side comments will still be executed on the server and
> sent down to the browser.  As such, if there is a server error caused
> within them it will block running the page.**

Comment: +1 You are correct, but you haven't answered the OP's *actual* question... which was **why** you have to do it like that

Comment: yep duh. thanks!! so if i can use <!-- for standard HTML in a .aspx but HAVE to use <%-- for asp in a .aspx then is it a good model to follow to just *always* use <%--?

Answer (score 2):

Client-side comments like `<!--` do not affect server side control parsing. So when your page is parsed, the parser is still processing the UpdatePanel and it looks like this to the parser:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">-->     
<!--</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the parser does not understand how to process the inner content between the tags. You need to use server side comments and then the parser will ignore the panel.

```
<%--<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
</asp:UpdatePanel>--%>
```